# Adobe Photoshop CS5 64bit Colour picker colour range is wrong and unable to set background colour

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs5

I have Adobe CS5 64 bit on a Windows 64 bit computer.
It used to work fine then today when I opened it to do some colour correction, the colour picker suddenly does not display the right colours, and I cannot set a foreground colour.

**Colour picker colour issue:**
This is the colour picker colour range when I double click on the foreground colour box. As you can see, it does not show the normal range and does not include the black and white.

[image: Current default foreground photoshop colour picker, there is no black or white]

The background one has a similar issue but shows a different set of colours:
[image: Background colour picker]

Additionally, it does not display the right colours even when I set the right settings. Here is a screenshot comparison of my colour picker on the right and a screenshot of a colour picker used in a tutorial online, on the left. Note that I have set all the numbers and percentages to match the one in the tutorial:
[image: Colour pickers compared photoshop]

**Trying to set foreground and background colours:**
When I select a colour from the colour swatches on the right, even if the foreground colour box is active, whatever colour I select only changes the background colour. My work around is select a colour I'd like for the foreground then since it is applied to the background, manually switch the background and foreground colours around.

Since I cannot select the foreground, this meant I could not change the colour of the text I was typing: I typed the right side (it was red by default, I did not choose it), then typed the left and then highlighted it, then selected a colour to differentiate it from the red text.  However, the colour I chose got set as the background colour in the colour box (not to the actual image), meanwhile, whatever colour I had as the foreground colour got applied to the text.

Any insights would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You have the **G** color channel selected (from R,G,B). The screenshot you're following has the **H** selected (from H,S,B). Click on the **H** radio button and you'll see the exact same color preview. You must have clicked on it by accident.

Note that it doesn't change the final color you select; look at your last image and you'll see the color values are exactly the same - even the color in the "New" box is exactly the same no matter what you select.

Comment: This is the right answer. The UI is just showing a different 'slice' of the color space. That's what the radio-buttons are for.

Comment: omg thanks for that, I can't believe it was that simple. But, the second issue - unable to select a foreground colour, hasn't been solved yet. Any ideas on that?